# Changing quality of video in iframe to another setting

Tags: iframe, youtube

I am embedding a youtube video into an iframe. Now the video quality has 2 settings: 360p and 240p. Now Youtube chooses 240 as the default everytime, and it looks crap. How can I change the default quality to be the highest possible, 360p in this case?

I tried setting the parameter ?hd=1 at the end of the video link, but it does not work:
like so:

```
<iframe title="Evolution of 4 String Quartet on BBC" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/D1GEH6VxQ-k?hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

I also played around with this developer tool from Google, which is quite cool btw, but no luck with the 380p...
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Answer (score 0):

You just want to use vq parameter instead of hd:

```
  <iframe title="Evolution of 4 String Quartet on BBC" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/D1GEH6VxQ-k?vq=medium" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

vq can also be: small, large, hd720, hd1080.